# Javascript, programmatically trigger file download in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, dom

I have a data uri in memory that I would like the user to download.

This fiddle works in chrome but not FF: http://jsfiddle.net/6W2TY/

When you click run it will download the tiny image in chrome and do nothing in FF.  Can anyone help me understand why it doesn't work in FF and what I need to do to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: the fiddle link isn't working.
Can you post the code in the question for posteritys sake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using the new (html5) [download attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download). <s>As far as I know this is only supported in Chrome and not (yet) in Firefox.</s>

**Update 3-2018**
This feature is now supported in [almost all major browsers](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=download) (No IE support).

### Alternative: Using location.href

Another way to force a download is to redirect the user to the image like this:

```
// generate the image
var img = ""

// then call a function maybe onClick or something
downloadImage(img);

function downloadImage(data) {
    location.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + data;
}
```

Or the short version

```
location.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAOCAYAAAAmL5yKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAABWSURBVDhPY0xISPh//0UOA7mAiVyNMH2jBjAwkBQGjD9KGBTEJ6OEO0kG2NvbMwCjnXwDsEU5SS5ANuDhjRCGJbPFSQsDdBfIyMhQZgDIQLK9QLWkDABPsQw5I+5qmAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
```

### Alternative: Server Side

As an alternative, if you are processing the image serverside you can force a download by setting the content-disposition header.

**PHP Example**

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"');
```

Comment: I'm building the image I want the user to be able to download client side.  Is there any way to let a user download a client side image that I have the data-uri for in FF?  It looks like the download attribute has been in chrome for over a year so I'm not sure FF has any plans to support it ever.

Comment: I added my answer to include an javascript only alternative. Is this something you can use?

Comment: Unfortunately location.href option means the file doesn't have the right mime type and I cannot set the default file name to anything reasonable, is there a way around that?  Marking this as answer regardless as it was quite helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you read this, but the only solution (workaround / hack) I can think of to set the mime type and filename is to post the image back to the server and return it again with the right headers.

Comment: Beware: this approach may trigger 'beforeunload' event

Answer (score 37):

I realize this is an old post, but I came across it when I had a similar problem downloading files in FF.  This may not have worked in FF at the time the question was written, but it does now.

```
a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.download = name;
a.href = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAOCAYAAAAmL5yKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAABWSURBVDhPY0xISPh//0UOA7mAiVyNMH2jBjAwkBQGjD9KGBTEJ6OEO0kG2NvbMwCjnXwDsEU5SS5ANuDhjRCGJbPFSQsDdBfIyMhQZgDIQLK9QLWkDABPsQw5I+5qmAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
a.click();
```

Changes from the original fiddle:

1. Add call to `document.body.appendChild(a);`
2. Change `triggerEvent()` to `a.click()`

Here is an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/70f91ao7/6/

Comment: The key is to attach it to the DOM for this approach to works under Firefox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873370/5841382

This will probably not work any more

Comment: Why do you need to add the element to the DOM? On Chrom (96) it works fine without