# jQuery: Trigger click event of <a> tag on key-down

Tags: jquery, html, download, anchor

I have created one html page that shows images & navigates to other images based on right and left arrow key press.

There is an anchor tag with **[download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)** attribute. The path of images which is displayed on screen currently is set to **href** of this tag through jquery.

Clicking this link downloads the image. I need that on pressing of down arrow, image should be downloaded. (in short this anchor tag's click event should be triggered.)

I tried jquery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function but not working. Below is my code.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
div.links {
    top: 95%;
    left: 45%;
    position: fixed;
}

a.dLink, a.nav {
    text-decoration: none;
}

label {
    background: #330033;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #CC9933;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="iNames"
        value="IMG1.jpg,IMG2.jpg,IMG3.jpg">
    <img class="pic" />
    <div class="links">
        <label class="prev">Prev</label>
        <a class="dLink" href="" download>
           <label>Download</label>
        </a>
        <label class="next">Next</label>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    iNames = ($("#iNames").val()).split(",");
                    total = iNames.length;
                    i = 0;
                    $("img.pic").attr("src",iNames[i]);
                    $("a.dLink").attr("href", $("img.pic").attr("src"));
                    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                        switch (e.which) {
                        case 37: // left
                            prev();
                            break;

                        case 39: // right
                            next();
                            break;
                        case 40: // down
                            $("a#dLink").trigger("click"); //this is not working
                            break;
                        default:
                            return; 
                        }
                    });

                    function next() {
                        i = i == total - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
                        setImage();
                    }
                    function prev() {
                        i = i == 0 ? total - 1 : i - 1;
                        setImage();
                    }
                    function setImage() {
                        $("img.pic").attr("src",iNames[i]);
                        $("a.dLink").attr("href", $("img.pic").attr("src"));
                    }
                    $("label.next").click(function() {
                        next();
                    });
                    $("label.prev").click(function() {
                        prev();
                    });
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript, programmatically trigger file download in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676649/javascript-programmatically-trigger-file-download-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger native click event calling DOM node method instead: {need to use class selector, not ID}

```
$(".dLink")[0].click();
```

Comment: Not working.. error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: This worked.. but didn't get difference between `$(".dLink")[0].click();` and `$("a.dLink").trigger("click");`

Comment: `.dLink` will trigger for any element with that class, while `a.dLink` will trigger only for mentioned class associated with any `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small typo.

Try this:

```
$("a.dLink")[0].click();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o2cgz853/)**

Since, `dLink` is the class applied to `<a>`. You have to use `a.dLink` selector.

Comment: I have only one anchor tag in page as shown in code + only one element with class "dLink". this worked..