# Firestorage downloading from download url doesn't download my file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firebase-storage

I am fetching a file via the download URL as described here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

This is the code I used

```
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        var blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open('GET', this.$data._downloadURL);
      xhr.send();
```

And I get a response with status 200 and in the preview I can see the image. But it doesn't seem to be downloading in my browser. How can I do that?

I tried putting a cors json file in the storage as well but it doesn't seem to have any imact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not told the script to do anything with the data. The part of your code that reads

```
xhr.onload = function(event) {
  var blob = xhr.response;
};
```

runs when the download is complete. Your data is in the `blob` variable. If you want to download it, you can try for instance the techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676649/javascript-programmatically-trigger-file-download-in-firefox) inside the `xhr.onload` function.